# MYSQL - Calculating if an angle is between two angles

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select all points from database just if my angle is between two another angles... I have this code in PHP and this works rly great:

```
public static function angle_between($value, $ang_a, $ang_b)
{
    $n = (360 + ($value % 360)) % 360;
    $a = (3600000 + $ang_a) % 360;
    $b = (3600000 + $ang_b) % 360;

    return ($a < $b) ? ($a <= $n && $n <= $b) : ($a <= $n || $n <= $b);
}
```

But how can I do this in SQL? I'm trying this of course

```
SELECT ... WHERE angle BETWEEN X AND Y
```

But I'm using the "angle tolerance" and this example does not work of course in this situation:

```
angle = 355;
x = (angle - 10)
y = (angle + 10);

SELECT * FROM ... WHERE angle BETWEEN 345 AND 5

// 5° cause 355°+10° = 365° = 5°
```

And of course is not between, but it is...

BTW: `angle_between(355, 345, 5); // true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to split your range in two ranges and then check:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE angle BETWEEN 345 AND 360
   OR angle BETWEEN 0 AND 5;
```

Comment: you're right... (min > max) ? angle BETWEEN $min AND 360 AND angle BETWEEN 0 AND $max : angle BETWEEN $min AND $max

Answer (score -1):

I think this can only be solved by a Stored Procedure, or client side processing to form the query before sending over to MySQL.